# unable to display two post per page in wordpress front-page.php

Tags: posts, permalinks

`'posts_per_page' => 2` is not working if assign `post_per_page` to `1` it will display 2 post per page and if I assign `post_per_page` to 2 or 3 it will display 3 post and when used 4 it will display 4 post. Why?

Comment: Do you have a sticky post?

Comment: yes, I have one sticky post.

Comment: That's your answer. Sticky posts do not count towards the posts per page.

Comment: thank you for clarification